# Updating MAC Address in a DHCP reservation removes other variables

Tags: powershell, dhcp

i have an odd issue for when i run this command:

```
Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation -computer name -ip 1.1.1.1 -clientid macaddress
```

it removes a few other variables, such as "root path". when I run get-dhcpreservation on an IP that has all of its variables set, "root path" is not something it returns, and it is not something that I can set with powershell -- plus, i'd rather it not be removed.

are there any other methods to update a dhcp reservations mac address?

Comment: So you run the `Set-Dhcp...` first, then run `Get-Dhcp...` and it doesn't return the other values it had prior to running `Set-Dhcp..`?

Comment: not exactly. when I run get-dhcp, it doesn't return the values of the root path. I have to manually go into dhcp to look at the reservation and it will be there. when I run set-dhcp on an IP that has its root path set, it then disappears out of the reservation.

if i go to dhcp and manually update the mac address, there is no issue with with the root path being removed. the goal would be to automate the mac address update with powershell, but removing the iscsi target kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Seems like an issue is recommend making a case on GitHub for that cmdlet. Does querying just that path property still return empty?

Comment: not sure, did not think to check that.

also not sure how i missed this earlier, but this looks promising : set/Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue

i think using that will fix the issue.

Comment: Hopefully it does!

Comment: it ended up working pretty well. set-dhcpserv4optionvalue has no available value for MAC addresses, but it was simple to get the values that Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation removes, update the mac address, and re add the deleted values back.

Comment: post an answer on this post and mark it as the answer. This way it'll help future readers in case they run into this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

after fiddling around with Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation there is really no way to set the mac address with that command without deleting option values that are set, such as iscsi targets. there is also seemingl

the fix was using Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue to store what would be deleted as a variable, use set-dhcpserver4reservation to set the MAC address, then use set-dhcpserverv4optionvalue to add back what was deleted.

not the most ideal solution but i was successfully able to update the mac address while preserving everything that the command was deleting.